# Assistance modifying a batch file to delete the C: drive

Tags: batch-file

Newbie question.

Would `cd "C:del *.*` delete all files within the C: drive?

I was also told if I add `del . /F /Q` it would bypass confirmation of the deletion, but I'm not 100% sure where to put it. Do I just add it onto the end like
`cd "C:del *.* del . /F /Q`?

Comment: This sounds fishy if you ask me. What application would you have for this ?

Comment: no it won't . what are you up to exactly? What have you tried and what does not work?

Comment: If you're trying to format the hard drive, I recommend using third-party software.

Comment: Duncubuntu. I have a hard drive with some extremely sensitive data on it and I want to get rid of everything on it. As for trying to bypass confirmation I am simply trying to experiment and learn a thing or two while im doing it

Answer (score 0):

#### This is a dangerous command. Be careful.

No, you probably want `del /F /Q .`.

The first part, `del`, is the command. This is telling it to delete something.

`/F /Q` are the options, denoted by the leading slash.

- `/F` means to force it, so for example if a file isn't writable it will still delete it if able. It also skips some other checks.
- `/Q` tells the program to be 'quiet', so less output will be generated than normal

`.`(dot) is the thing to delete, which is the place you currently are. If you are currently in `C:\` (ie if the terminal displays `C:\>` at the beginning of every line), then it will be that that it deletes.

Note that I have only shown what you should type (`del /F /Q .`) and *not*  what the entire line should look like when you're done (`C:\> del /F /Q .`). However, if this is going in a batch file then you want the first form only.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a destructive command and is provided merely to answer the query - don't try it at home or prank friends with it.**

This will delete all files that are not locked, or opened for exclusive access by a program.

```
del c:\* /s /f /q /a
```

It will not delete every file in a Windows system drive and will not remove directories.

Comment: For that you might want `rmdir`.

Comment: @Paul  `rmdir` and the alias `rd` will not remove folders which contain open or locked files either.

Comment: I never suggested that rmdir would delete open files. If the OP wants to delete all files of a running OS, then the plan should be reconsidered

Comment: @paul The point is that you CANNOT delete `all` files from a running Windows NT series OS.  Permissions, locked files, UAC will all stop you from doing it.

Comment: That is what I implied when saying that the plan should be reconsidered.